# Getting Bad Request only on Gingerbread phones and simulator

Tags: android

I am facing a weird problem. I've a piece of code that makes a call to a server. The code works fine when I use Kitkat emulator. However, the same code does not work on Gingerbread phones or emulator. I always get 400 Bad Request from the server. I checked on the server. The error is:

client sent HTTP/1.1 request without hostname (see RFC2616 section 14.23):

Apache is not configured as virtual host.

here is the code I am using:

public void makeServerCall(String serverUrl, String postString) {
            URL url = new URL(serverURL + ESS_AUTHENTICATE_URL);

```
        connection =  (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setDoOutput(true); 
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.setRequestMethod(HTTP_POST);

        //forcing user agent to a well known user agent with a hope it will work :-)
        connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; PPC; en-US; rv:1.3.1)");

        String base64Tenant = "Basic " + Base64.encodeToString( auth.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT);
        connection.setRequestProperty(AUTHENTICATE_HEADER, base64Tenant);

        connection.addRequestProperty("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
        connection.addRequestProperty("Pragma", "no-cache");
        connection.setUseCaches(false);



        connection.setRequestProperty( "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", "UTF-8");

        System.setProperty("http.keepAlive", "false");

        connection.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(postString.getBytes().length);

        // Send request

        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
        out.print(postString);
        out.close();

        int respCode = connection.getResponseCode();
        Log.i(TAG, "Response code = " + respCode);
        if (respCode != 200) {

            is = connection.getErrorStream();
            if (is != null) {
                String response = getStringFromStream(is);
                Log.d(TAG, "Error occured: " + response);
                is.close();
            }
        }
        else {
        // process success Response
        }
}
```

---

Here is the wireshark capture I got when I run the code on Kitkat simulator
    POST /removed_path HTTP/1.1

Accept-Charset: UTF-8

User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; PPC; en-US; rv:1.3.1)

Authorization: Basic ASVGQVVMVEASDFw==

Cache-Control: no-cache

Pragma: no-cache

Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Host: correcthost.myserver.com

Connection: Keep-Alive

Accept-Encoding: gzip

Content-Length: 49

this is the post stringHTTP/1.1 200 OK

### Date: Tue, 04 Feb 2014 07:52:42 GMT

Here is the wireshark capture from Gingerbread

POST /removed_path HTTP/1.1

Accept-Charset: UTF-8

User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; PPC; en-US; rv:1.3.1)

Authorization: Basic ASVGQVVMVEASDFw==

Cache-Control: no-cache

Pragma: no-cache

Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Content-Length: 49

Host: correcthost.myserver.com

Connection: Keep-Alive

### Accept-Encoding: gzip

The only difference between the two wiresharks difference is the order of content-length.

I've access to server too. I am not sure, I can change anything there because it is working for recent versions of Android and iOS. Any ideas on what is going wrong?

Comment: I know this is old post but for people facing similar problems, here error message is clear- "Host" header is not being detected. Problem could be order in which the headers are being sent. I've faced similar issue, my code was working for Android 4.3 but not on Android 2.3. After some investigation, I noticed that "Host" header was missing in my case. I was using HttpUrlConnection btw.